# Add PostID to URL of Custom Post

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, permalinks

I searched and saw several similar questions but not a useful answer.
I have a plugin that automatically assigns as url the format

```
website.com\event\this-is-the-post-title
```

Even if I change the Permalink structure the plugin doesn't follow it and I would like to have the format as follows (add post id before title) because I expect multiple posts having the same title (they are events)

```
website.com\event\1234-this-is-the-post-title
```

How do I add automatically the post id?
Would I need url rewrite functions as well?

Thank you

Comment: Check below code

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('init', 'custom_perma_link');

function custom_perma_link(){

global $wp_rewrite; 
//Write the rule
$wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure('/%post_id%-%postname%/'); 
//Set the option
update_option( "rewrite_rules", FALSE ); 
//Flush the rules and tell it to write htaccess
if(is_admin())
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules( true );

}
```

Try this code

Comment: Hi Mujeebu, is this going to change the default permalink structure for all posts or only the custom? I still want to keep the default permalink structure as is and my goal is to change the URL on a per post basis